# How can I pass a list of image names from a csv file to the find command?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, find

So I have a csv file with a list of image names formatted as such:

```
FPC-84WB.jpg
Arctic-Blue.jpg
Azuria.jpg
Azuria-Reflective.jpg
BLACK-REFLECTIVE.jpg
Bronze.jpg
Champagne.jpg
Copper.jpg
Light-Green.jpg
Orange.jpg
Pacific-Blue.jpg
....
last-image.jpg
```

I want to use `find /var/www/html/ -name [name of image] -exec convert [options] {} \;` to batch convert all these images without having to go and find their exact directory or path. So how can I pass each line of the csv to the find command to batch convert all these images.

I tried googling to figure this out, but everything that came up was about passing output from `find` to another command or file, while I want the reverse.

EDIT: `pics.csv` that I'm using to test on local machine:

```
delta-heat-logo.jpg
two-dogs-designs-logo.jpg
modern-flames-logo.jpg
polyscience-logo.jpg
real-fyre-logo.jpg
the-good-one-logo.jpg
man-law-logo.jpg
american-outdoor-grill-logo.jpg
afd-logo.jpg
KAGspritesheet.png
tec-logo.jpg
ogr-logo.jpg
FPDspritesheet.png
hpc-logo.jpg
primo-logo.jpg
american-fireglass-logo.jpg
napoleon-logo.jpg
cavo-logo.jpg
coc-logo.jpg
fire-magic-logo.jpg
spotix-logo.jpg
fornetto-logo.jpg
Blaze-Grills-Logo.jpg
bge-logo.jpg
DCS-logo.jpg
greatco-logo.jpg
DCS-Logo-HP.jpg
skytech-logo.jpg
afd-logo_1.jpg
homecrest-logo.jpg
Lynx-Logo-BW-White.jpg
fusionchef-logo.jpg
amantii-logo.jpg
pics.txt
good-one-logo.jpg
jatex-logo.jpg
Warming-Trends.jpg
polyscience-logo_1.jpg
SPOTIXspritesheet.png
poly-science-logo.jpg
summerset-logo.jpg
twin-eagles-logo.jpg
```

WORKING COMMAND FOR OTHERS WHO FACE THE SAME PROBLEM IS:

`find [path] \( $(sed 's/.*/-o -name &/; 1s/-o //' [csv file]) \) -exec convert {} [options] {} \;`

Comment: Do you know that none of the names listed in the file contain any spaces or tabs (or quotes, or dollar signs)?  Presumably, none of the names contain any newlines?  Spaces in the path leading to the files aren't an issue at the moment.  And how big is the list of images?  A few hundred names or less, or is it up into the many thousands?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler none of the images have whitespace, and the list is a few hundred long. I just need to trim the whitespace at the end of every line and pass them one line at a time to the `find` command. I don't know the exact path of any of the files, we have 10s or thousands of images scattered throughout our server as we're using magento and the product images directory is pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names shown all use only characters from the portable file name code set (`A-Za-z0-9_-.`).  Assuming that holds good in the part of the list we can't see, and that the list is not more than a few hundred entries long, then you can use something like this:

```
find /var/www/html/ \( $(sed 's/.*/-o -name &/; 1s/-o //' file.csv) \) \
     -exec convert [options] {} \;
```

If the converter program accepts multiple arguments in a single invocation, replace the `\;` with `+`.

The idea is that you will generate a command looking like:

```
find /var/www/html/ ( 
           -name FPC-84WB.jpg
        -o -name Arctic-Blue.jpg
        -o -name Azuria.jpg
        -o -name Azuria-Reflective.jpg
        -o -name BLACK-REFLECTIVE.jpg
        -o -name Bronze.jpg
        -o -name Champagne.jpg
        -o -name Copper.jpg
        -o -name Light-Green.jpg
        -o -name Orange.jpg
        -o -name Pacific-Blue.jpg
        ....
        -o -name last-image.jpg
    ) -exec convert [options] {} ;
```

Where I'm showing what `find` would see (I've removed the backslashes, and white space separates the arguments).

The significance of the questions about the characters in the base file names is that using the portable filename character set avoids the need to quote every file name, which makes the job a lot simpler than if you have to deal with (some of the) characters outside of the portable filename character set.  The size of the list of files is important not to overflow the limit on the length of a single command — that's often large (as in 100 KiB or more) but it isn't unlimited.

Comment: I'm getting a `find: paths must precede expression:  -exec` error, but the path is preceding `-exec`. I'm guessing we're canceling it out with a `\\` at some point.

Comment: That's curious.  When I run it verbatim (on a Mac), I get `find: /var/www/html/: No such file or directory` (which is accurate); when I replace that path with `$HOME/lib` (existing medium size directory — no JPG files, though), I runs without error (and without any output).  I created the first 5 names in your list in the current directory, and used `echo` before `convert` and got those names. Check that you copied things correctly.  Or show what you executed with the files list containing just 4 names.  You were including the backslashes before the grouping parentheses to the `find` command.

Comment: Here is the exact command `find /home/nate/Pictures/Manufacturer_favicons/ \( $(sed 's/.*/-o -name &/; 1s/-o //' pics.csv) \) \ -exec convert -quality 75 {} \;`. I'm testing this on a few images on my local machine first. I'll edit my original post to show the `.csv` I'm using to test this.

Comment: The backslash between `\)` and `-exec` is not wanted unless the command extends over a newline.  It's hard to tell in a comment whether it is all on one line.  However, if you put it all on one line and included that backslash, you get an error — I got `find:  -exec: unknown primary or operator` (where there's an extra space before the `-exec`).

Comment: With GNU `find`, as opposed to BSD (macOS) `find`, I get the 'paths must precede expression' error instead of 'unknown primary or operator' error.

Comment: @JonathanLefler The error was actually my fault. After removing the `"\"` you were speaking of I was getting an error about no image present. I forgot that you need to define what the converted image will be named even if you want to replace the original. So the working command is 

`find [path] \( $(sed 's/.*/-o -name &/; 1s/-o //' pics.csv) \)  -exec convert {} -quality 75 {} \;`

Comment: Your list of file names shown in the update to the question is 'clean'; all the names use characters from the portable file name character set only.  That is not part of your problem.  Beware any trailing blank line in the files list.  You could add `/^[[:space:]]*$/d;` before the first `s///` command in the script to avoid problems with them.

Comment: Use `_```\\```_` (without the underscores) to get the backslash ```\```  into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've accepted your answer as the solution.

Comment: The simple file names make it a lot easier to deal with.  If we had to deal with file names like `mega$$$.jpg` or `aunt jemima in reno.jpg` or `not (repeat not!) the truth.jpg`, we'd be in a world of hurt.